# I can't insert multirow in firebirdsql

Tags: sql, insert, firebird

I know in sql server to

```
Insert into table ( id, name) values ('1', 'John'), ('2','Peter');
```

but in **firebid 1.5** i don't know how to insert the values.

I tried with

```
Insert into table ( id, name) 
select '1', 'John' from rdb$database 
union all select '2', 'Peter' from rdb$database;
```

but does it not work

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation says](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-insert.html):

> **UNION allowed in feeding SELECT**
>
> Changed in: 2.0
>
> Description: A SELECT query used in an INSERT statement may now be a
>   UNION.

Since you're using version 1.5, it looks like you'll have to use multiple insert statements.

Comment: So, do you get an error message?  What's different between your query and the example from the documentation?

Comment: */
/*!!! Error occured !!!
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 4, char 1.
union.

*/

Comment: Now I'm no firebird expert, but that looks like it's stumbling over the `union`.

Comment: @CristoforCostin Did you backup and restore your database? Newer functionality in Firebird sometimes doesn't work if the database still has the on-disk structure of Firebird 1.5.